# Integration by parts $\int xe^{x^2} dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find with integration by parts $$\int xe^{x^2} dx$$.

---

$$\int xe^{x^2} dx$$

Let $u(x) = x \ \ \ v^{'}(x) = e^{x^2}$

Now I can write the integral as $$\int xe^{x^2} dx = x \int e^{x^2} dx - \int\left(\int e^{x^2} dx \right) dx$$

Even after trying everything I am unable to solve $v^{'}(x) = e^{x^2}$ for $v(x)$.

---

I can do this question substitution $u = x^2$ but I told use integration by parts to do this question. What should I do ?

Comment: No need to do any black magic operation on this one : $\int xe^{x^2} = \frac12\int 2xe^{x^2} = \frac12e^{x^2}$...

Comment: There is no closed form for $v(x)$. You are going to have to use a different $u,v'$.

Comment: Are there any limits of integration?

Comment: @zahbaz No, I need to find indefinite integral.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you know that ?

Comment: There are, via advanced proofs, certain functions which have no closed form (in terms o elementary functions.) when integrated. $e^{x^2}$ is one of them. I can't honestly say I've ever seen the proof, personally.

Comment: Maybe the by parts bit was a cut/paste error? Just a thought.

Comment: @Paul Maybe I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $u=e^{x^2}$ then $du=2xe^{x^2}$ and $v=\frac{x^2}{2}$ so
$$\int xe^{x^2}dx=\frac{x^2e^{x^2}}{2}-\int x^3e^{x^2}dx$$
Take $u=e^{x^2}$ and $dv=x^3$ then
$$\int x^3e^{x^2}dx=\frac{x^4}{4}e^{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\int x^5e^{x^2}dx$$
Similary
$$\int x^5e^{x^2}dx=\frac{x^6}{6}e^{x^2}-\frac{1}{3}\int x^7e^{x^2}dx$$
In general $$\int x^{2n+1}e^{x^2}dx=\frac{x^{2n+2}}{2n+2}e^{x^2}-\frac{1}{n+1}\int x^{2n+3}e^{x^2}dx$$
From that we can take a few terms and notice that $$\int xe^{x^2}dx=\frac{x^2}{2}e^{x^2}-\frac{x^4}{4}e^{x^2}+\frac{x^6}{12}e^{x^2}-\frac{x^8}{48}e^{x^2}+\frac{x^{10}}{240}e^{x^2}+\cdots\\\int xe^{x^2}dx=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k}}{k!}$$Now with few adjustments you'll get$$e^{-x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{k!}=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{k!}=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k}}{k!}\\\int xe^{x^2}dx=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}\left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}+C$$

Comment: Why you don't write $dx$ in the end ?

Comment: @A---B Bad habit I guess (edited though)

Comment: I would have accepted your answer happily if I known anything about infinite sums. I cannot understand the adjustments to $$\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k}}{k!}$$.

Comment: @A---B Fair enough,this isn't a elementary approach,if you wanna learn more here's a link to the [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) series of $e^x$.plugging in $(-x^2)$ instead of $x$ you get the above sum without $(-1)^k$ and without the term that corresponds to $k=0$ which is why the $1$

Comment: This is definitely a proof from "The Book", specifically [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-made-difficult-Carl-Linderholm/dp/0529045524).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I guess this answer was done [by the book](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+book) :)

Answer (score 3):

If you **absolutely want** to write the integration in the form of an integration by part use:
$$
v'=xe^{x^2} \quad \rightarrow \quad v=\frac{1}{2}e^{x^2}
$$
and
$$
u=1 \quad \rightarrow \quad u'=0
$$

Comment: Haha this answer will surely infuriate the teacher :)

Comment: Well I take this happily but I am looking for an answer that does not use $u = c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Seriously OP you have been trolled.

Comment: @samjoe I know but I don't have any other answer.

Comment: The primitive if $v(x)=e^{x^2}$ can be expressed only using the **erf** function. So really I don't see any  way to use integration by parts in a ''not joke'' manner.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with the change of variable
$$
u=e^{x^2}, \qquad du =2xe^{x^2},
$$ one has 
$$
\int xe^{x^2}dx=\frac12\int du
$$ which is easy to evaluate.

Comment: Sir he has already said that he needs by parts approach.

Comment: Did you read to the end of the question?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's why I wrote 'Alternatively'...

Comment: But "alternatively" the OP has already said that he/she knows this answer. I ask again, did you read to the end of the question?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Here I prove it. I'm not writing only for the OP... I must confess I did not read the end of the question, but I think my answer worth to be written.

Comment: Thank Olivier but I need to do by integration by parts.

Comment: I mean "worths"

Answer (score 1):

Take $e^{x^2}$ as the first function and apply rule of by parts, you get

$\int e^{x^2}x dx =e^{x^2}\frac{x^2}{2}-\int x^3.e^{x^2}dx$.....$(A)$

Now $\int x^3e^{x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int t.e^t dt$ where $x^2=t$ and $2xdx=dt$ (**Assuming that your teacher didn't mean to completely reject substitution**).
On integration, it gives  $\frac{1}{2}e^t(t-1)$ or $\frac{1}{2}e^{x^2}(x^2-1)$.

Substitute it in $(A)$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would have accepted your answer if kingw3 did not post his answer :).