# Integrate $\int{ e^{{x}^{2}-x} \cdot x \cdot e^x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate $\int{ e^{{x}^{2}-x} \cdot x \cdot e^x} dx$

I'd like to know how to do it because I need it for another task. Here is what I tried:

$$\int{ e^{{x}^{2}-x} \cdot x \cdot e^x} dx = \int{e^{x^{2}-x+x} \cdot x} \text{ }dx = \int{e^{x^{2}} \cdot x} \text{ }dx$$

Now substitute (especially at this step I'm not sure). Let $s=x^2$, then:

$$s'=2x \Leftrightarrow 2x = \frac{ds}{dx} \iff dx = \frac{1}{2x} ds$$

Insert these into $\int{e^{x^{2}} \cdot x} \text{ }dx$:

$$\int{e^{s} \cdot x} \cdot \frac{1}{2x} \text{ }ds= \frac{1}{2}\int{e^{s} ds} = \frac{1}{2}e^{s}+c = \frac{1}{2}e^{x^{2}}+c$$

---

I hope everything is alright? If it's correct, is there a faster way to solve it? Because substitution is confusing for me :s

Comment: it is correct your result

Comment: In this case substitution is the by far the fastest most intuitive way, if you don't believe me here's a very complex non-intuitive method using [integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2217850/integration-by-parts-int-xex2-dx/2217959#2217959)

Comment: Yeah it's absolutely correct!!

Comment: @kingW3 Isn't using parts too tedious for this?

Comment: @tatan Yes certainly, it is both tedious and unpractical, I just wanted to give an example how this easy to do substitution turns into a monster when trying a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always differentiate your answer and see what you get. In this case
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{x^{2}}+c\right)=\frac{1}{2}2x e^{x^{2}}=xe^{x^{2}}
$$
by the chain rule. So you are correct.